# Usar puertos GPIO´S como pines de RX y TX

Tags: c

Buenas tardes, estoy usando un pic12f675, necesito enviar por serial (a un módulo bluetooth) datos de temperatura, sin embargo, el pic no tiene pines de rx y tx cómo podría por software enviar los datos? Estoy usando pic c para la programación.

Comment: y si compartes el código que has intentado?

Comment: Es que no se si se puede o no

Comment: Este es un foro de programación y los ejemplos están a la orden del día. Si no puedes publicar el código que tienes (lo cual podría tener cierto sentido), siempre puedes poner un ejemplo mínimo que permita ofrecer soluciones compatibles con tu código.

Answer (score 0):

En `CCS C` puedes crear una `UART` virtual. Por ejemplo si eliges el puerto `6` como `TX` y `7` como `RX` en el inicio, deberías declarar el `UART` virtual de esta manera:

```
#use rs232(baud=9600,xmint=PIN_D6,rcv=PIN_D7,stream=DatoX,parity=N,bits=0)
```

Luego para leer:

```
char Palabra;
Palabra=fgetc(DatoX);
```

Para escribir:

```
char msj;
msj=4;
fprintc(DatoX,msj);
```